# CSS advance selector - is posible?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have question about CSS selectors. I have below structure - I can only modiffy CSS - I don't have access to modify html or JS.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="open">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="top">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Class open will be toggled. Can I make selector when:

1. div in 4 line has open - div with class top => .top {top:50px}
2. div in 4 line not has open - div with class top =>  .top{top:0px;}

This is possible?

Comment: No impossible with CSS , to get current top

Comment: Will become possible if you could add `open` class to the outermost parent inside `.wrapper`.

Comment: @MohammadUsman - you have right but unfortunatly I can edit only CSS.

Comment: In that case, not possible in pure CSS (until CSS manages to give us a workable parent selector).

Comment: By definition, CSS cascades downward, there is no way to move back up the tree to find a parent element's siblings, which would be required for this situation. I suggest you rethink your process, could you perhaps apply a class to the `wrapper` which affects both the child classes?

Comment: Problem is - I base only on change css.

Comment: As it has already been said, cannot be done with css.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.wrapper div:not(.open){
    ...
}
```

You will need to adjust it to the get the correct DIV, because this will affect all of them inside .wrapper

In your case it looks like you need something like:

```
.wrapper > div > div > div:not(...){...}
```

However, that is a bad practice.

You can read some more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: This is not what I need : )

Comment: Sorry mate, this is what I understood from the question.